# How to capture the line delimiting character(s) in a platform independent way?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following expression

```
/^\S+\s*$/m.exec("a\nb\n")[0]
```

returns just "a" but not the line delimiter, although [`\s` should match `\n`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

By experimenting I found out that the following expression does somehow what I want:

```
/^\S+\s*$\n\r?/m.exec("a\nb\n")[0]
```

But now the regular expression is platform dependent.

How to include the line delimiting character(s) into the match in a platform independent way?

Comment: `(?=[\r\n])\r?\n?` - assert that there is a newline character, then match any of `CR` (old Mac), `LF` (Linux) or `CRLF` (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I got it myself.

Instead of matching the end of line it seems to be better to match the beginning of the next line. This:

```
/^\S+\s*^/m.exec("a\nb\n")[0]
```

returns "a\n".